# selection limit function not working on checkbox form reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox, ecmascript-6, web-applications

I have a react component that checkboxes fetched from json, each section of the checkbox can contain up to 5 checkboxes, i am trying to set the limit in each section to maximum of 2 selections, however it is not working as it should, the main component is **itemlist.js**, and the checkboxes come from **checkbox.js**, here is a live snippet of what i am trying to do, https://codesandbox.io/embed/84lo55n689?fontsize=14, the changes are made in **checkbox.js**, I commented out the function and it changes for demonstration, since it makes the app crash.

**Checkbox.js**

```
    import React from "react";
import "./Checkbox.css";

/* class Checkboxes extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    currentData: [],
    limit: 2

  }}
 componentDidMount() {

  selectData(id, event){
    let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
    if (isSelected) {
      if (this.state.currentData.length < this.state.limit) {
        this.setState({ currentData: [...currentData, id] })
      }
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        currentData:
          this.state.currentData.filter((item) => id !== item)
      })
    }
  }}
 render() { */

const Checkboxes = props => {
  const id = /*this.*/ props.childId + /*this.*/ props.childp;

  return (
    <form className="form">
      <div>
        <h2>{/*this.*/ props.title}</h2>
        {/*this.*/ props.options &&
          /*this.*/ props.options.map(item => {
            return (
              <div className="inputGroup">
                <input
                  id={id + item.name}
                  name="checkbox"
                  type="checkbox"
                  //     checked={this.state.currentData.indexOf(id + item.name) >= 0}
                  //  onChange={this.selectData.bind(this, id + item.name)}
                />
                <label htmlFor={id + item.name}>{item.name} </label>
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}; //}}

export default Checkboxes;
```

**Itemlist.js**

```
...

  <Checkboxes
                        key={index}
                        title={item.name}
                        myKey={index}
                        options={item.children}
                        childk={item.id}
                      />
...
```

Comment: If i don't understand bad. you need to be able to call only 2 checkboxes?

Comment: @JordiCastillo yes, so if the pop shows 5 checkboxes under a section, i can only check 2 of them and the other 3 wont be clickable.

Comment: Where is your "click" event for checkbox.js?

Comment: //     checked={this.state.currentData.indexOf(id + item.name) >= 0}
                  //  onChange={this.selectData.bind(this, id + item.name)} 

i suppose..

Comment: This can't be because is commented!

Comment: Transform it to smart component, and share us code again, i think that could be a reason

Comment: @JordiCastillo I made comments because it crashes, here is without comments https://codesandbox.io/embed/ww75wrr49k?fontsize=14

Comment: I saw the same as before, as i said the last comment, make a smart component (with `class Checkboxes extends React.Component {` etc..)

Comment: @JordiCastillo Here, https://codesandbox.io/embed/ww75wrr49k?fontsize=14 (I updated the last save) check checkbox.js, thanks.

Comment: Tell us if it is what you need please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No needs to know which element is checked or not in global,

First change currentData to 0 in this.state

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentData: 0,
      limit: 2
    };
  }
```

Then change selectData function

```
selectData(id, event) {
    let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
    if (isSelected) {
      if (this.state.currentData < this.state.limit) {
        this.setState({ currentData: this.state.currentData+1 });
      }else{
        event.preventDefault()
        event.currentTarget.checked = false;
      }
    } else {
      this.setState({currentData: this.state.currentData - 1});
    }
  }
```

And remove checked attribute from input (when page load is 0)
´

```
<div className="inputGroup">
   <input
       id={id + item.name}
       name="checkbox"
       type="checkbox"
       onChange={this.selectData.bind(this, id + item.name)}
   />
<label htmlFor={id + item.name}>{item.name} </label>
</div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/j4yyx9v6l5?fontsize=14